# adding fragment in activity from fragment not working in Pixel XL android version 8.0.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo

Recently i updated my pixel xl mobile to android version 8.0.0(Orio) after that

when I add fragment in my application by calling a method in main activity from fragment, it is not working in pixel but same code is working in other mobiles like Sony Xperia android version: 5.1.1 and Samsung S8 android version 7.0

how to solve this ?

my Code(In Kotlin) for calling method setUsernamePassword() in Main activity:

**(activity as MainActivity).setUsernamePassword()**

**Main Activity Code**:

```
import android.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    addFragmentToActivity(R.id.loginFragment,LoginFragment())
    val loginText = findViewById(R.id.login_textView) as TextView
    loginText.setOnClickListener {
        addFragmentToActivity(R.id.loginFragment,LoginFragment())
    }

    val registerText = findViewById(R.id.register_textView) as TextView
    registerText.setOnClickListener {
        addFragmentToActivity(R.id.registerFragment,RegisterFragment())
    }
}

private fun addFragmentToActivity(frameId: Int,fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(frameId,fragment).addToBackStack(null)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}

 fun setUsernamePassword() {
    addFragmentToActivity(R.id.setUsernamePassword,SetUsernamePasswordFragment())
}



}
```

Comment: can you post main activity code?

Comment: main activity code added
please check

Comment: Add something from LogCat. Simply adding code wouldn't help.